# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error when I try this

```
function e(e, a, s) {
var o = r("#" + s + "canvas")[0],
        n = r("#" + s + "canvas"),
        i = o.getContext("2d"),
        l = o.width / 2,
        d = o.height / 2;
i.beginPath(), i.arc(l, d, r(n).attr("data-radius"), 0, 2 * Math.PI, !1), i.fillStyle = "transparent", i.fill(), i.lineWidth = r(n).attr("data-width"), i.strokeStyle = r(n).attr("data-progressBarBackground"), i.stroke(), i.closePath(), i.beginPath(), i.arc(l, d, r(n).attr("data-radius"), -t(90), -t(90) + t(e / 100 * 360), !1), i.fillStyle = "transparent", i.fill(), i.lineWidth = r(n).attr("data-width"), i.strokeStyle = r(n).attr("data-stroke"), i.stroke(), i.closePath(), "true" == r(n).attr("data-text").toLocaleLowerCase() && r("#" + s + " .clProg").val(a + ("true" == r(n).attr("data-percent").toLocaleLowerCase() ? "%" : ""))
}
r.fn.circularloader = function(t) {
    function a() {
        h.beginPath(), h.arc(u, f, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !1), h.fillStyle = n.backgroundColor, h.fill(), h.lineWidth = l, h.strokeStyle = n.progressBarBackground, h.stroke(), h.closePath(), c > 0 && e(c, d, o)
    }

    var s = this[0],
        o = s.id;
```

I'm getting the above-mentioned error when at "s.id". I even tried to declare the id but that couldn't resolve the error.

Comment: Have you tried to console `s`?

Comment: Add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with proper formatting which isn't minified or obfuscated.